# Change joomla menu from source code

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla3.0, megamenu

can I change the joomla menu from source code?

I want to test if I have an open session, and if I have it , I want to change the Login menu, into My Account menu !

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please make it as the correct answer to help other users find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a template override of the menu.

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Then inside that use:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest())
{
    //Insert HTML if not logged in
}
else
{
    //Insert HTML if logged  in
}
```